I got Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null
I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null

Here is my code
Update.cshtml:
@model WebBanHang.Models.Product
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<form asp-action="Update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Update Product</h2>
    <hr />
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageUrl))
            {
                <img src="/@Model.ImageUrl" style="width:300px" id="previewImage" />
            }
            else
            {
                <span>No image available</span>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group pb-2">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pb-2">
                <label>Discription</label>
<textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pb-2">
                <label>Price</label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pb-2">
                <label>Category</label>

                <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="@ViewBag.CategoryList" class="form-control">

                    <option disabled selected>==Select category===</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @* <img src="/@Model.ImageUrl" style="width:300px" id="previewImage" /> *@
            <div class="form-group pb-2">
                <label>Product Image</label>
                <input asp-for="ImageUrl" type="file" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button>
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]').forEach(input => {
            input.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
                const file = event.target.files[0];
                if (file) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        const img = document.getElementById("previewImage");
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

ProductController.cs:
using WebBanHang.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProjectName.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment _hosting;

        public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db,  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hosting)
        {
            _db = db;
            _hosting = hosting;
        }

        //Hiển thị danh sách sản phẩm
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var productList = _db.Products.Include(x => x.Category).ToList();
            return View(productList);
        }

        //Hiển thị form thêm sản phẩm mới
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            //truyền danh sách thể loại cho View để sinh ra điều khiển DropDownList
            ViewBag.CategoryList = _db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });

            return View();
        }

        //Xử lý thêm sản phẩm
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(Product product, IFormFile ImageUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //kiem tra hop le
            {
                if (ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    //xu ly upload và lưu ảnh đại diện
                    product.ImageUrl = SaveImage(ImageUrl);
                }

                //thêm product vào table Product
                _db.Products.Add(product);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["success"] = "Product inserted success";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CategoryList = _db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });

            return View();
        }

        //Hiển thị form cập nhật sản phẩm
        public IActionResult Update(int id)
        {
            var product = _db.Products.Find(id);

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //truyền danh sách thể loại cho View để sinh ra điều khiển DropDownList
            ViewBag.CategoryList = _db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });

            return View(product);
        }

        //Xử lý cập nhật sản phẩm
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(Product product, IFormFile ImageUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //kiem tra hop le
            {
                var existingProduct = _db.Products.Find(product.Id);

                if (ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    //xu ly upload và lưu ảnh đại diện mới
                    product.ImageUrl = SaveImage(ImageUrl);

                    //xóa ảnh cũ (nếu có)
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingProduct.ImageUrl))
                    {
                        var oldFilePath = Path.Combine(_hosting.WebRootPath,
                        existingProduct.ImageUrl);

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(oldFilePath))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(oldFilePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    product.ImageUrl = existingProduct.ImageUrl;
                }

                //cập nhật product vào table Product
                existingProduct.Name = product.Name;
                existingProduct.Description = product.Description;
                existingProduct.Price = product.Price;
                existingProduct.CategoryId = product.CategoryId;
                existingProduct.ImageUrl = product.ImageUrl;

                _db.SaveChanges();

                TempData["success"] = "Product updated success";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CategoryList = _db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });

            return View();
        }

        private string SaveImage(IFormFile image)
        {
            //đặt lại tên file cần lưu
            var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
            //lay duong dan luu tru wwwroot tren server
            var path = Path.Combine(_hosting.WebRootPath, @"images/products");
            var saveFile = Path.Combine(path, filename);

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(saveFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                image.CopyTo(filestream);
            }

            return @"images/products/" + filename;
        }

        //Hiển thị form xác nhận xóa sản phẩm
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var product = _db.Products.Find(id);

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }

        //Xử lý xóa sản phẩm
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var product = _db.Products.Find(id);

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // xoá hình cũ của sản phẩm
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ImageUrl))
            {
                var oldFilePath = Path.Combine(_hosting.WebRootPath, product.ImageUrl);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(oldFilePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(oldFilePath);
                }
            }

            // xoa san pham khoi CSDL
            _db.Products.Remove(product);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Product deleted success";

            //chuyen den action index
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}

I have no idea what's going on with my code. I can delete product but can't add or update it in the database.
I'm also searching for solutions a lot on the internet, but I can't seem to find which is the same as my problem.
Thanks for looking into this! Hope you guys have a good day!

How is your model Product defined?

Hi @Wayne, do you set breakpoint to your backend and check the code? You return view without the model which may be the reason.

Check your Update/Add action, you can see it needs judge the ModelState and return different result. If it is valid, it will redirect to Index action.  If it is not valid, it will return view without the model.

I can delete product but can't add or update it in the database.

Then check your delete action, it will redirect to Index action. That is to say, you Index action is correct.
So it seems the NullReferenceException caused by the return view without model. Firstly change the code to:
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Update(Product product, IFormFile ImageUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            //...
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryList = _db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        });

        return View(product);   //change here...
    }

Then you need set breakpoint in visual studio to if clause to check why the ModelState is invalid to achieve the Update/Add operation in the database. For example:

